# Sencha App loads from bootstrap.json instead of app.json making it slow

Tags: javascript, extjs, launch

This is a very Naive question probably. But I have 2 EXTJS applications and one of them loads very fast (with just app.json loading at launch) and the other one loads very slow with several calls to the backend that are not needed at launch time.
Both applications have same config in Application.js and app.js. How can I control what to load at launch time?

One more difference -> For the faster loading app, In Firebug, the app starts with app.json but the slower running app starts with bootstrap.json which has tons other files inside of it. How can i rectify this?

```
/**
 * The main application class. An instance of this class is created by app.js when it calls
 * Ext.application(). This is the ideal place to handle application launch and initialization
 * details.
 */
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'MyApp',

    views: [
        // TODO: add views here
    ],

    controllers: [
        'Root'
        // TODO: add controllers here
    ],

    stores: [
        // TODO: add stores here
    ],

    launch: function () {
        // TODO - Launch the application
    }
});


/*
 * This file is generated and updated by Sencha Cmd. You can edit this file as
 * needed for your application, but these edits will have to be merged by
 * Sencha Cmd when upgrading.
 */
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    extend: 'MyApp.Application',

    autoCreateViewport: 'MyApp.view.main.Main'

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Most customizations should be made to ExtjsView.Application. If you need to
    // customize this file, doing so below this section reduces the likelihood
    // of merge conflicts when upgrading to new versions of Sencha Cmd.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
});
```

Comment: Can you provide us with more code sowe can see the diefferences? And why is the namespace of your main view incorrect?

Comment: @Tarabass in ExtJS which file decides what should be loaded first at launch time? I saw the difference between the 2 aps, and the faster loading app has more config in bootstrap.js about all the stores and models.

Comment: I found one more difference -> For the faster loading app, In Firebug, the app starts with app.json but the slower running app starts with bootstrap.json which has tons other files inside of it. How can i rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out my issue-> My backend was pointing to 
/myApp/extjs/build/development 
while it should have been pointing to

/myApp/extjs/build/production

Thank you @Tarabass for all your help

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Feel free to upvote my answer and mark it as asnwered.

Answer (score 0):

I think, without seeing any screenshots of your network tabs of devtools, that the one with bootstrap.json is your development environment. So nothing is concatenated or minified. The fast app is build with Sencha Cmd and is optimized for production, is concatenated, is minified, is using cache and ready for deployment.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am building both the apps with 'sencha app build'  and I do have sencha cmd. I check the Microloader.js which has 
Ext.manifest = Ext.manifest || "bootstrap"; at the end of the file. I added a print statement to check th emanifest and it is undfined. In my other app which loads with app.json, at the same print i got 'app'